# Php Execute Shell Command and pipe the password

Tags: php, shell-exec

I am attempting to run a command as root from a php page, is there any way to run shell_exec(`su - root -c 'apt-get update'`) (for example) and pass the password to the shell? Or is there another way to run a root command from php and pass the password to the command.

I would prefer not to do the follow:

```
edit the /etc/sudoers file;
install the ssh2 php extension;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used an entirely PHP based SSH implementation called [phpseclib](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/).

This way the user doesn't have to install a php extension like ssh2, just download the files and include them in your script.  Then you can pipe the password to the command, like so:

```
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . 'phpseclib');
include('Net/SSH2.php');

 $ssh = new Net_SSH2('localhost');
 if (!$ssh->login('root', $password)) {
     exit('Login Failed');
  }

 echo $ssh->exec('whoami');
```

This php code will return the value "root".  Any commands you run at this time will be run as root.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a `setuid` wrapper for the command you want to run, and execute that wrapper instead:

```
echo '#!/bin/bash' > /path/to/wrapper.sh
echo 'apt-get update' >> /path/to/wrapper.sh
chown root /path/to/wrapper.sh
chmod a+x,u+s /path/to/wrapper.sh
```

Comment: So this is a script I would have to set up and change the permissions to before I run the php script?  I was hoping to have the users I am making this for not have to use the terminal at all... entirely from the web browser.

Comment: So, if your PHP code had the root password hard-coded in it (I'm not even going to talk about how irresponsible that would be), what would your user do if they change their root password?

Comment: They would supply the password at runtime and php would pipe the password to the terminal.  It would not be hardcoded and would not store the password.  The variable would hopefully be passed in https POST.  This is for a setup/install php script, should only need the permissions for the initial setup.